# How to find the right combination of numbers which fits to multiple certain values

Tags: excel

There are 8 pallets loaded with cartons, but we are not sure which carton is loaded on which pallet.

**Information we have :**
-There are 32 cartons and weight of each carton is known.
-There are 8 pallets and weight of each pallet without pallet weight is known.

[image: pallet weights]
[image: 32 items and each weights]

In this situation, is there a way to allocate carton weight to each pallet so that we can know which carton is out into which pallet?

-I tried to use solver function but it did not help as they could only find one combination per pallet.
-Then I tried to use sumproduct to find all combinations, but I could only find combinations per pallet and couldn't find the combinations of weights which matches all the pallets.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/find-combinations-that-equal-given-sum-excel/

It would be great if anyone can help with this.

Comment: I would approach this with the solver, but I would have the two tables as a single table ie x,y and use binary to represent if an article is in the pallet or not. If you had provided data then I might have attempted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

So, did this for the first 2 pallets, however you run into a Solver limit - you can purchase the larger version to overcome this or do for 2 pallets at a time...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment! However, all the combinations need to fit into 8 pallets at the same time so I will try to see if I can purchase the bigger version. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could use 4 sheets and copy the items not allocated to the next sheet.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my reply. I tried to calculate them per 2 pallets but it didn't work out as all the combinations should fit into certain values (8 different weights per pallet) at a time. Thank you for the help though.